# How to overload a specific layer of CSS3 layered multiple background images

Tags: css, background-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change only one of multiple backgrounds on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845224/change-only-one-of-multiple-backgrounds-on-hover)

If you had a CSS declaration like this:

```
.selector {
    background: url(image.png), url(image2.png);
}
```

and on :hover you wanted to change just the first layer, e.g.

```
.selector:hover {
    background: url(image3.png), url(image2.png);
}
```

Is there a way to update the image to image3.png without having to redeclare the rest of the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, there isn't any way to do that.